# Add isoclines and/or direction field to plot

Tags: r, plot, package

I was solving differential equations with R when I came across a problem: I needed to add Isoclines and a direction field to my plot, but I didn't know how to. What package should I install/what function should I call/should I do it all manually?

Comment: `library('sos') findFn('isoclines')` gives me `LVCompGames` package: this generates a plot of isoclines and initial points..

Comment: I think you *may* need to do it manually; I suspect a lot of people have written their own code to do this, but I don't know of a packaged version (and based on @agstudy's answer, I doubt there is one -- "isocline" should be a pretty reliable search keyword).  Finding isoclines is (unfortunately) not entirely trivial ...

Comment: sorry the package name is `primer` and LVCompGames  is the isoclines function

Comment: http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/graph/quiver_episode_2,128

Comment: Another possible starting point is to use `vectorplot()` and `contourplot()` from the **rasterVis** package. Here's an example: http://rastervis.r-forge.r-project.org/#vectorplot. (Set `margin=FALSE` to suppress plotting of the marginal distributions.)

Comment: http://www.math.pitt.edu/~bard/xpp/help/xppncline.html suggests computing nullclines as the zero contours of a 2D surface, which then suggests a good way to do it in R (I will show how to implement in R if you provide a reproducible example: http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is not an answer, but just a summary of the answers given in  comments:

- the `LVCompGames` in  `primer` package give this plot:

[image]

1. This is the solution given by @[Ben Bolker](http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/graph/quiver_episode_2,128). The solution is based on the `graphics` package and `filled.contour` function.

[image]

- Then @Josh O'Brien suggestion the `rasterVis` package with `vectorplot` function

[image]

I think all answers can be customized if you give us more information of what you wish as output.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot. I am really sorry for bothering you with this question, now I see it was not that difficult. Thank you again and hope I will be able to contribute to the site.

Comment: You are welcom. if the answer meet your resuirement you can acept it by checking the check box at left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great package called [phaseR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/phaseR/). It uses the ODE solver from the package [deSolve](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deSolve/index.html) and let's you easily add nullclines, trajectories and so forth.
Just be sure to name the parameters of your ODE function "t", "y" and "parameters". Otherwise the phaseR functions will give an error:

> Error in deriv(t = 0, y = c(x[i], y[j]), parameters = parameters) :
>   unused arguments (y = c(x[i], y[j]), parameters = parameters)

Here is a working code example for the Lotka-Volterra predator-prey system:

```
require(deSolve) 
require(phaseR)

model.LV <- function(t, y, parameters){
  with(as.list(parameters),{

    N<-y[1] 
    P<-y[2]
    dN <- a*N - b*N*P  
    dP <- c*N*P -d*P

    list(c(dN,dP))
  })
}

params.LV<-c(a=0.4, b=0.3, c=0.1, d=0.2)

data.LV<-as.data.frame(lsoda(c(N=1,P=1),seq(1,250,by=0.5), model.LV, params.LV))
# plot the time series of both populations
plot(data.LV$time,data.LV$N, main="Time series of L-V equations", xlab="time", 
     ylab="Population densities N, P",
     type="l", col="green", 
     ylim=c(0,max(data.LV$N,data.LV$C)))
lines(data.LV$time,data.LV$P,col="red")

# plot the trajectories of the system
plot(data.LV$N, data.LV$P, type="l", col="blue", main="Trajectory of L-V equations",
     xlab="Prey density N", ylab="Predator density P", xlim=c(0,5), ylim=c(0,3))
#add Nullclines
nullclines(model.LV, x.lim=c(0.1,5),y.lim=c(0.1,3), parameters=params.LV, system="two.dim", colour=c("green","red"), add=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `my.symbols` function in the TeachingDemos package allows you to define your own symbols to add to existing plots.  The support function `ms.arrows` already codes basic arrows to add to a plot, you can easily modify it (or the other ms. functions) to create a different symbol to add.